# Hadoop installation on Mac El Capitan

Tags: hadoop, installation, hadoop2, osx-elcapitan, hadoop-native-library

I tried to install hadoop-2.7.2 on Mac "OSX El Capitan" and getting error related to Native library:

```
$ hadoop checknative -a

WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: **Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable**
Native library checking:
hadoop:  false 
zlib:    false 
snappy:  false 
lz4:     false 
bzip2:   false 
openssl: false
```

For installation I used command hadoop brew install, I did all the required configuration changes but still no solution. After this I also tried to install hadoop using package available on Apache website but even there also I am facing same issue related to Native library.

Answer (score 1):

You must build your own distribution, however bzip2 is still possibly not supported in Mac. this [blog](http://blog.itsolvs.com/2016/02/building-hadoop-30-on-mac-os-x-el.html) may help you.

You may choose to ignore this warning, it does not harm.